# Windows System Programming

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface, systems-programming

I'm really excited to learn system programming on the windows platform. I just started reading "Programming Windows Fifth Edition" and I noticed that it's mostly GUI-Oriented.

Excuse me for a maybe-dumb question, but isn't all this can be used in an IDE instead of writing dozens of lines of code to write a windows form or a drop-down menu ?

Is there a way to avoid all this and directly tackle system programming ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Win32 API, you can use a resource editor (e.g., for the Visual C++ Express Edition, you can get [something like this](http://www.resedit.net/) that works as an external editor).  I can't remember if the full Visual Studio still comes with one.

The resource editor will allow you to write scripts to automate some of your GUI building, but by and large it still has to be done "by hand."  You have seen some of the downsides to this, but the upside is it provides a very powerful and extensible interface with Windows.

Comment: Yes, the full editions of VS still come with a resource editor. But it hasn't changed much (if at all) over the years. The ResEdit app that you recommend looks *way* better. It might even be a pleasure to use. I'll really have to try this some time...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of exactly what you mean by "System Programming" but in any case you have to learn the basics of the platform and programming language first. Programming on Windows, I'd say it's essential to have at least a basic knowledge of GUI programming.

Comment: It's a university project i took. We're asked to program a simple malware and demonstrate it. And then show its countermeasures. Everything should be done with WinAPI and not MFC using the C/C++ programming language.

Comment: To make simple Malware, having detailed knowledge of the WinAPI, GUI message system etc. is a very good start.

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.amazon.com/WPF-4-Unleashed-Adam-Nathan/dp/0672331195/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1311145232&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672331195)

The whole unleashed series are very good.

WPF is one of the newest ways to do windows software development.

Another up and coming way is HTML5 and javascript. See the next version of windows. I don't remember the codename.